# Created an Auto ML Job, registered the model and created an end point but the schema of the test input is failing

Tags: machine-learning, azure-ai, azure-auto-ml

I have used the azure auto ml low code editor way of building a forecasting model (predict the demand of a product based on a 8 year time series data)  by following this guide :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-automated-ml-forecast?view=azureml-api-2

Where by we have done the below steps :

- Create and load a dataset.
- Configure and run an automated ML experiment.
- Specify forecasting settings.
- Deploy the best model.
- Create an endpoint for the model

However while testing the endpoint from the studio test section, I am getting the below error :

[image]

On checking the logs, could find an input data format error as below :
[image]
The schema of the CSV that was uploaded as dataset for training the model is shared below. Please help with some leads.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information, I have reproduced the issue.
[image]
It seems the input expected input format required is different.

To fix this you can use the below code snippet to get the correct format:

```py
import json

# Define the input_data dictionary
input_data = {
    "instant": 1,
    "date": "1/1/2013",
    "season": 1,
    "yr": 0,
    "mnth": 1,
    "weekday": 6,
    "weathersit": 2,
    "temp": 0.344167,
    "atemp": 0.363625,
    "hum": 0.805833,
    "windspeed": 0.160446,
    "casual": 331,
    "registered": 654
}

# Convert input_data dictionary to the desired format
formatted_data = {
    "input_data": json.dumps({
        "columns": list(input_data.keys()),
        "index": [0],
        "data": [list(input_data.values())]
    })
}

# Print the formatted data
print(json.dumps(formatted_data, indent=2))
```

**Output:**

```json
{
  "input_data": "{\"columns\": [\"instant\", \"date\", \"season\", \"yr\", \"mnth\", \"weekday\", \"weathersit\", \"temp\", \"atemp\", \"hum\", \"windspeed\", \"casual\", \"registered\"], \"index\": [0], \"data\": [[1, \"1/1/2011\", 1, 0, 1, 6, 2, 0.344167, 0.363625, 0.805833, 0.160446, 331, 654]]}"
}
```

With the above output format, the test executed successfully.
[image]